# Problem in magnetism (theoretical)

Tags: electromagnetism

When we move a conducting rod perpendicular to its length in a magnetic field perpendicular to direction of motion of rod,is charge density induced at only the ends of the rod or throughout the length of it?The second answer seems to be more correct to me but i cannot be sure.....

Answer (score 1):

Charges will shift until the electric force at each point equals the magnetic force. This requires a distribution of charge.

Comment: Will the charge only be accumulated at the ends of the rod?

Comment: No. That would give a dipole field which would not be uniform in the rod.